# F12 Boot Menu disappeared after editing boot entries. Any way to restore it?

Tags: linux, windows, boot, multi-boot, uefi

This is interesting.

I have a Lenovo Z580 laptop on which I could easily access a one-time boot-menu on startup by pressing the `F12` key. Until yesterday. Now, the boot menu just doesn't show up.

I am curious to know what caused this and if there's a way at all to fix it. As per my understanding, GRUB or `efibootmgr` can't really overwrite BIOS' keys. I would really appreciate any kind of help :)

## Details

- I have dual-booted Windows 10 and Linux for a long time on this machine.
- Yesterday I decided to dual boot Arch, but with Secure Boot enabled.
- Note that I was able to reach the boot-menu with `F12` to boot into the installation medium here.
- To complete setting up `shim`, I created a boot-menu entry for it with `efibootmgr`.

  - You can read on shim [here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Unified_Extensible_Firmware_Interface/Secure_Boot#Set_up_shim).
  - I deleted an old `proxmox` entry before creating this one. But I don't think that should be relevant.
- Note that I was able to access the boot-menu with `F12` key even after that.
- The setup was a success. And I decided to wipe out Arch.
- I followed the same [instructions](https://aniketteredesai.com/blog/remove-uefi-dualboot/) I follow every time (never had a problem before, neither on this machine nor on others)

  - Except this time I had two boot-menu entries to remove -- the `shim` one and the one `grub-install` created. Which I did.
- And the next thing I know, I wasn't able to access the boot-menu with `F12` after a few minutes.
- PS: `efibootmgr` was executed in a `arch-chroot` environment from the live installation medium.

## Solutions Tried

- Restoring the boot configuration backup (config before deleting the entries)

  - The backup was taken with `bcdedit` on Windows 10
- Removing laptop's battery
- Pressing `Fn` key in addition to `F12` (which is not necessary in my laptop's case)
- Using an external keyboard for `F12` presses
- It's wireless. But I have used it to trigger Boot Menu before.
- Disable Fast Boot in Windows
- It was disabled the entire time.
- Resetting BIOS
- Disabling & Re-enabling USB Boot
- Disabling & Re-enabling Secure Boot
- Removing & Re-setting BIOS' admin password
- Re-flashing/Updating BIOS with the update package provided by Lenovo

  - BIOS was already up-to-date before

## Observations

- Windows 10 boots fine.
- I can access the Boot Menu with Windows 10's `Shift+Restart` > "UEFI Firmware Settings" method.
- I can access the Boot Menu with the `Novo` (Recovery) button, which is specific to some Lenovo laptops.
- I am able to boot into drives without any issues if I access the boot-menu with any of the above mentioned methods.
- Yet another dual boot install was a success.
- Adding/deleting entries with `efibootmgr` works with the new install.
- `F2` works fine and takes me to BIOS.
- There's no switch in the BIOS to enable/disable the Boot Menu, as is the case with some notebooks.
- Other software register the `F12` key-press after booting the OS. So, the key isn't a problem.
- There's no Fast Boot option in BIOS.

## A Peculiar Observation

- Before I attempted to restore the `bcdbackup`, `F12` sort of worked actually.

  - It landed me into BIOS, instead of the one-time Boot Menu it always opened.
- After the restore attempt though, `F12` just doesn't do anything.

Answer (score 0):

Disable fastboot in Windows and BIOS.

Comment: I don't have that option in BIOS (it's a fairly old laptop) and it was disabled in Windows the entire time. Sorry, I forgot to include this detail in my post. Added it now :) Thx.